# Bessel function Integral from a physical problem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\,\mathrm{I}_{0}\left(x\right)
\mathrm{I}_{1}\left(x\right)\mathrm{K}_{1}^{2}\left(x\right)}{ax\,\mathrm{K}_{0}\left(x\right)\mathrm{I}_{1}\left(x\right) + 1}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

I've tried to use wolfram alpha but it said that the integral was not convergent. But physically it is supposed to converge. I have no idea how to solve this right now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram alpha seems to be correct.  Maple confirms that the integrand is asymptotic to $1/(4x)$ as $x \to \infty$, and thus the integral diverges.

Comment: $$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\,\mathrm{I}_{0}\left(x\right)
\mathrm{I}_{1}\left(x\right)\mathrm{K}_{1}^{2}\left(bx\right)}{ax\,\mathrm{K}_{0}\left(x\right)\mathrm{I}_{1}\left(x\right) + 1}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$ The original problem was this, where the coefficient b goes to 1 in the limit.